# Deploying CS-Cart on Jelastic cloud

Tags: nginx, cs-cart, jelastic

does anybody tried to deploy CS-Cart to Jelastic cloud?
There's an [instruction](http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/install/nginx.html) on how to setup CS-Cart on nginx, but i want to set up on native Jelastic environment with nginx, not vps.
Confused with nginx configuration.

Comment: You should be able to do that from step 2. Just create your Jelastic environment with nginx(PHP) a MySQL/MariaDB node first. If you have trouble please give details and we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

We have performed the test installation of CS-Cart v. 4.3.10 downloaded from the official site.

Used the instruction you have provided. But for the test install we just need to enable imagemagick for php and mod_rewrite for nginx.

1. Let's create a test environment with nginx-php and mariaDB.
   We used nginx 1.10.1, php 5.6, and mariaDB 5.5.51
2. Deploy downloaded archive with CS-Cart into nginx instance via Jelastic dashboard.
   You can find out how to deploy application [here](https://docs.jelastic.com/whole-project-deploying).
3. Now we can make some basic configurations on nginx and php.
   This [article](https://docs.jelastic.com/application-configuration) will help you with configurations editing.
   To enable mod_rewrite for nginx add the string below to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, section **location**:

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

Like this:

[image: nginx mod_rewrite]

Don't forget to click the "Save" button on the top bar of code editor.

The same way edit /etc/php.ini.
Uncomment the line **extension=imagick.so** in the [imagick] section.

[image: php imagick]

Save the php.ini and restart the nginx instance:

[image: restart node]

4. Proceed from step 5 of the CS-Cart [installation guide](http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/install/nginx.html).

That's it for the basic installation.
You can check our installation via this [link](http://cs-cart.demo.jelastic.com/), the portal was filled up with demo data, so we didn't describe the process of db creation. This shouldn't make any trouble for you.

You can try this on your hoster's platform, in case you will experience any difficulties, please contact support service.

Have a nice day!